# Duplicate Navbar Wordpress (+ Behaviour)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a theme with a navigation bar in the header and I'd like to add a new identical navigation bar under the existing one and it should behave in exactly the same way.
I registered two new menus called "topmenushop" and "topsidemenushop".

Once I copy the HTML code, it inserts me the second navigation bar but it doesn't have the same behaviour of the first one.

Navigation working: User Menu "Menu utenti"

Second navigation bar_topsidemenushop "Animali" (on click shows the sub-menu of the menu above) 
+ topmenushop (on click doesn't show the sub-menu, it shows it only in the mobile version, adding some elements that are not present inside the mobile version of the first navigation and once I click on the toggle, it opens me the menu of the first navigation)

The support wrote me:

> For that, you need to create new class for the same and manage the
>   toggle of that newly created menu via new JS code

but I have no idea on how to do it or which sources I could read. Is it a CSS problem? JQuery problem? HTML one?

---

Below you see the orginal code that I copied in order to have a second nav-bar.

```
     <div class="bottom-header-wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="tg-container">

            <?php
            $menu_location  = 'secondary';
            $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
            $menu_object    = (isset($menu_locations[$menu_location]) ? wp_get_nav_menu_object($menu_locations[$menu_location]) : null);
            $menu_name      = (isset($menu_object->name) ? $menu_object->name : '');
            if ( has_nav_menu( $menu_location ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="category-menu">
                <div class="category-toggle">
                    <?php echo esc_html($menu_name); ?><i class="fa fa-navicon"> </i>
                </div>
                <nav id="category-navigation" class="category-menu-wrapper hide" role="navigation">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                            'theme_location' => 'secondary',
                            'menu_id'        => 'category-menu',
                            'fallback_cb'    => 'false'
                        )
                    );
                    ?>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="toggle-wrap"><span class="toggle"><i class="fa fa-reorder"> </i></span></div>
                <?php wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                        'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                    )
                );
                ?>
           </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

Here there's my modification

```
         </div>
               <div class="bottom-header-wrapper clearfix">
               <div class="tg-container">

            <?php
            $menu_location  = 'topsidemenushop';
            $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
            $menu_object    = (isset($menu_locations[$menu_location]) ? wp_get_nav_menu_object($menu_locations[$menu_location]) : null);
            $menu_name      = (isset($menu_object->name) ? $menu_object->name : '');
            if ( has_nav_menu( $menu_location ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="category-menu">
                <div class="category-toggle">
                    <?php echo esc_html($menu_name); ?><i class="fa fa-navicon"> </i>
                </div>
                <nav id="category-navigation" class="category-menu-wrapper hide" role="navigation">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                            'theme_location' => 'topsidemenushop',
                            'menu_id'        => 'animali',
                            'fallback_cb'    => 'false'
                        )
                    );
                    ?>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <div class="toggle-wrap"><span class="toggle"><i class="fa fa-reorder"> </i></span></div>
                <?php wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                        'theme_location' => 'topmenushop',
                        'menu_id'        => 'animali_important',
                    )
                );
                ?>
           </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

Here's the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4ExS.png)